# Cannot convert value of type Query to required type 'java.lang.String' for property on Spring Batch MongoItemReader

Tags: java, spring, mongodb, spring-batch, spring-data-mongodb

I'm writing a Spring Batch job that uses the out-of-the-box `MongoItemReader`. My job is configured via XML. I am setting the "query" property via the setter that accepts a type `org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.query.Query`.

However, occasionally, my job will fail due to a type error, but other times it will pass ok despite not making any changes to the code.

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot convert value of type 'org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.query.Query' to required type 'java.lang.String' for property 'query': no matching editors or conversion strategy found
    at org.springframework.beans.TypeConverterDelegate.convertIfNecessary(TypeConverterDelegate.java:262)
    at org.springframework.beans.AbstractNestablePropertyAccessor.convertIfNecessary(AbstractNestablePropertyAccessor.java:585)
    ... 27 more
```

The following is the job configuration with the reader beans

```xml
    <!--  Job Definition  -->
    <b:job id="reviewJob">
        <b:step id="processReviews">
            <b:tasklet>
                <b:chunk reader="mongoItemReader"
                         processor="reviewProcessor"
                         writer="mongoItemWriter"
                         commit-interval="10" />
            </b:tasklet>
        </b:step>
    </b:job>

    <!--  Reader  -->

    <bean id="mongoItemReader" class="org.springframework.batch.item.data.MongoItemReader" >
        <property name="template" ref="mongoTemplate" />
        <property name="collection" value="Reviews" />
        <property name="targetType" value="com.company.batch.model.Review" />
        <property name="sort">
            <map>
                <entry key="id" value="#{T(org.springframework.data.domain.Sort.Direction).ASC}" />
            </map>
        </property>
        <property name="query">
            <bean class="com.company.batch.factory.MongoQueryFactoryBean" />
        </property>
        <property name="maxItemCount" value="10" />
    </bean>
```

This is my factory bean class:

```java
import org.springframework.beans.factory.FactoryBean;
import org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.query.Criteria;
import org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.query.Query;

public class MongoQueryFactoryBean implements FactoryBean<Query> {

    @Override
    public Query getObject() throws Exception {
        Query query = new Query();
        Criteria criteria = new Criteria();
        criteria.orOperator(
                Criteria.where("status").is("A"),
                Criteria.where("status").is("B")
        );
        query.addCriteria(criteria);
        return query;
    }

    @Override
    public Class<Query> getObjectType() {
        return Query.class;
    }

...
```

Answer (score 1):

java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot convert value of type 'org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.query.Query' to required type 'java.lang.String' for property 'query': no matching editors or conversion strategy found

The above exception means it expects String but getting Query object in the field query.

If I look at the specifications for MongoItemReader

https://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/4.0.x/api/org/springframework/batch/item/data/MongoItemReader.html#setQuery-org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.query.Query-

It does accept String or object of type org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.query.Query

In your case you are setting a object of FactoryBean to query field.

Have your implementation of Query Bean or simply set query string.

Comment: The FactoryBean pattern allows me to inject a Query more easily using XML-based bean configuration. Query primarily uses a builder pattern more suited for Java-based bean configuration. If I wanted to leverage the class's builder pattern, I think FactoryBean is best-suited here. See [this official blog post](https://spring.io/blog/2011/08/09/what-s-a-factorybean)

Comment: Seems like what you want to do can be achieved by creating custom MongoItemReader by extending it and provide custom implementation to get query object. Current implementation of MongoItemReader does not support the way you want it.

Comment: Spring handles calling getObject() behind the scenes since my class implements FactoryBean as discussed in the blog post that I linked. To be clear, this configuration works _most_ of the time, but will occasionally fail due to the exception stated in my question.

Comment: I am also facing the similar issue. I am using the xml to setQuery. In my application, we are setting query as String and it was working well until we updated from spring batch 3.X to spring batch 4.X. In spring batch 3.X, there is only one setQuery method in MongoItemReader vs there are 2 setQuery method in MongoItemReader which seems to be a cause of confusion for application. For me, it works sometime after startup and other times it doesn't. Did you found the solution?

Comment: @k_b I wasn't able to find a solution. My application was for ad hoc usage locally, so while not suitable for a production environment, I am currently just dealing with it.